# Simple dropdown not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu with jquery but is not working for IE8, any ideas why ?

I have already tried a couple of alternative solutions and I know that there are more simple ways to approach a simple dropdown but I really want to know why this code is not working on IE8, hope somedody can help.

```
<nav class="navAplicacio">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li><li><a href="#">Suport</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Surt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Torna</a></li>
        <li><button class="btn-usuari" type="button"><span class="nom_usuari">${nomUsuari}</span><i>(${nomGroup}) </i> <span class="ico"><img src="${images_folder}/escudo.jpg" alt="Escut Aj. de Martorelles"></span><span class="caret"></span></button></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

    jQuery(".btn-usuari").click(function()
    {
        var X=jQuery(this).attr('id');
        if(X==1)
        {
            jQuery(".dp-menu").hide();
            jQuery(this).attr('id', '0'); 
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery(".dp-menu").show();
            jQuery(this).attr('id', '1');
        }
});

jQuery(".dp-menu").mouseup(function()
{
    return false
});

jQuery(".btn-usuari").mouseup(function()
{
    return false
});

jQuery(document).mouseup(function()
    {
        jQuery(".dp-menu").hide();
        jQuery(".btn-usuari").attr('id', '');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where have you given the `ID` as `1`? `if(X==1)` this doesn't work!

Comment: And where's the menu items?

Comment: Please read the post again cause i think you are missing the whole thing here @PraveenKumar

 else
        {
            jQuery(".dp-menu").show();
           jQuery(this).attr('id', '1');
        }

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you including? And does your saying it doesn't work in IE8 mean that it *does* work in IE >=9 or Chrome, FF, etc.?

Comment: @Lowtrux Have a look at my answer in **IE 7 also**!!! It works clean!

Comment: Jquery 2 for modern browsers and 1 for IE<9 and yeah is working fine in IE>=9,Chrome and FF @nnnnnn

Comment: jQuery version doesn't matter. Can you have a look at the fiddle?

Comment: Yeah i just tested and is not working on IE8 @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are a few things here.

1. You should not use `id` as a flag. Because, the numeric value you are setting for `id` doesn't work in IE browser! Instead of that, use `data-*` attributes, or best, use a `class`!
2. And if you are just using `.mouseup()` and `.mousedown` for hiding and showing something, just use CSS, don't go for JavaScript! That's costly!

**Solution:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-usuari").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-usuari + .menu {display: none;}
.btn-usuari.open + .menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<nav class="navAplicacio">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Suport</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Surt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Torna</a></li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn-usuari" type="button">
        <span class="nom_usuari">Username?</span>
        <i>(Group) </i>
        <span class="ico"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/16/16" alt="Escut Aj. de Martorelles" /></span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Your example is not working on IE8 under WinXP @Praveen Kumar, so i can't use it.

Comment: @Lowtrux Can you change the line: `.btn-usuari.open + .menu {display: initial;}` to `.btn-usuari.open + .menu {display: block;}` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Just wondering what do i have to add if i want to close the dropdown when the user clicks outside of it in any part of the document.

Comment: Use this: `$("body").click(function () {$(".open").removeClass("open");});`

Comment: i guess this wont work since .dp-menu is inside the body tag so when you click in any part of the document (includint the button itself) this will hide the dropdown, so the dropdown will never show even when you click the button.

Comment: Actually yes, But you could take this as a starting point and that body of the function should not execute when it is inside any dropdown.